# Broken Image Box in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, report, ssrs-2019

I have a few lines breaking up my report.  When I run the report from the server or development I get a "broken image" box directly under my lines.  I have tried to make the line a box or list box.  The only way I can seem to get to work is to remove the line.  Is this something I just have to deal with?

[image: Screen shot of the problem.]

Comment: What browser are you using, what version of SSRS? Also it would be helpful if you can edit your question and show the actual report design.

Comment: I have tried to run the report on Chrome and IE.  I designed the report in Report Builder 2019.  

Sorry, this is my first question I was not aware that I could display the image in the question @aduguid edit my post to show the error I am getting.